# Calling an cryptography applet on html page

Tags: java, applet, cryptography

I have created an applet to perform cryptographic operations like encryption, decryption.
I need to call this applet on html page so that i can provide this facility to user who will access this html page. As applet is related to cryptographic operations, it will be accessing private data of the user from his system.

So i need the exact procedure to call such applet on html page. What all things do i need to take care during calling such applet on html page?

Answer (score 2):

A cryptographic Applet is no different than other applets. Moreover, encryption does not imply that you access private data of the user. As for calling the Applet, just take a look at the Oracle tutorials.

To perform cryptography on the users system, you need to make sure you don't use key sizes that require the unlimited strength cryptography policy files from Oracle (unless you want to ask every user to configure their systems).

To have access to private files you need to sign your Applets with a key that is trusted by the Java runtime system. You may use one of the pre-installed root certificates for that or import your own (again, asking the user to configure their systems).

Personally I do *anything* within my company to fall in this trap. You are much better off with a full featured Java WebStart application. Otherwise you will have to deal with multiple browsers, HTML, JavaScript and Applets. Coming from somebody that programmed such Applets himself: Java in the browser has *failed*.